# Error when checking input: expected conv2d_4_input to have shape (100, 100, 1) but got array with shape (100, 100, 3)

Tags: python, arrays, image, tensorflow, np

I get the following error when I try to run my skin cancer detection model. I have a set of images stored under train folder which I have used to train my model.

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout,Activation,Flatten,Conv2D,MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.constraints import max_norm
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LeakyReLU
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
opt=Adam(learning_rate=0.0005)

epochs = 40
batch_size = 128
X=np.asarray(X)
y=np.asarray(y)
cvscores = []
for train, test in kfold.split(X, y):
print(train)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), input_shape=(100,100,1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1))

model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors

model.add(Dense(128,kernel_initializer='normal'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=opt,
              metrics=['accuracy'])






model.fit(X, y, validation_split=0.3,epochs= epochs, batch_size= batch_size, verbose=0)

scores = model.evaluate(X[test], y[test], verbose=0)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
cvscores.append(scores[1] * 100)
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

del model

print("%.2f%% (+/- %.2f%%)" % (np.mean(cvscores), np.std(cvscores)))
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you're expecting a grayscale (1-channel) image but your dataset contains color (3-channel) images.   Look at tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale

Answer (score 0):

The image you have in your datasets have 3 channels (size 100x100x3) but your model takes as input 100x100x1 images. Modify the input shape to 100,100,3 in order to avoid the error:

```
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), input_shape=(100,100,3)))
```

instead of:

```
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), input_shape=(100,100,1)))
```

Comment: i modified the code to model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), input_shape=(100,100,3))) and now i get the folowing error:
  ValueError: Tensor("Pow:0", shape=(), dtype=float32) must be from the same graph as Tensor("conv2d/kernel:0", shape=(), dtype=resource) (graphs are <tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph object at 0x7f7bf9e4f750> and <tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph object at 0x7f7b9b9c7390>).